# Spring @Conditional context not giving the beans from beanFactory

Tags: java, spring

I have a setup  like this :

```
@Configuration
class DBConfig{

@Bean(name="dbTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate template(){
return new JdbcTemplate()

}
}


@Service
@Conditional(value=MyCondition.class)
class ABC{

}

class MyCondition implements Condition{
@Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        System.out.println(context.getBeanFactory().getBean("dbTemplate"));
    }
}
```

The issue is that System.out.println(context.getBeanFactory().getBean("dbTemplate")); is faling with a bean not found exception from within the Condition class eventhough the bean is available . Please explain why this is so